# liferay doesn`t see class

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I`ve added dependency to pom.xml, but i get this error, What to do?

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;`enter code here`
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName());


    private static DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
    }

    static {
        Properties property = new Properties();
        try {

            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            property.load(input);
            dataSource = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(property);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Maven pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>3.60.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.taglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.oval</groupId>
            <artifactId>oval</artifactId>
            <version>1.90</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Error: 2019-04-09 07:58:39.927 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-8][PortalImpl:6899] javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667) at com.liferay.taglib.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:173) at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:747) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl$IndirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl.java:202) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:79) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.TransferHeadersHelperImpl$TransferHeadersRequestDispatcher.include(TransferHeadersHelperImpl.java:162) at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutTypeControllerImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutTypeControllerImpl.java:171) at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutImpl.java:904) at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:407) at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:174) at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._processActionPerform(PortalRequestProcessor.java:706) at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:646) at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:194) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.process(MainServlet.java:1067) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:598) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:575) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103) at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:372) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:98) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103) at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:340) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:360) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:260) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144) at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:372) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:398) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:205) at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:142) at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.lambda$render$0(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126) at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper._render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:183) at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:124) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:212) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:192) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:84) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:568) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:340) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:154) at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:175) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:94) at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:728) ... 146 more Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667) at com.liferay.taglib.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:173) at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:2144) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl$IndirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl.java:202) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:79) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53) at com.liferay.portal.servlet.TransferHeadersHelperImpl$TransferHeadersRequestDispatcher.include(TransferHeadersHelperImpl.java:162) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._render(PortletContainerImpl.java:870) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$render$2(PortletContainerImpl.java:216) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:395) ... 160 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory at com.aimprosoft.connection.ConnectionFactory.(ConnectionFactory.java:31) at com.aimprosoft.dao.impl.DepartmentDaoImp.readAll(DepartmentDaoImp.java:56) at com.aimprosoft.service.impl.AbstractService.readAll(AbstractService.java:18) at com.aimprosoft.portlet.MainPortlet.doView(MainPortlet.java:36) at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:397) at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:291) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:127) at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:58) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71) at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:564) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:660) at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:357) at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.lambda$render$0(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:280) at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet._render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:383) at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:278) at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1534) ... 170 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory cannot be found by com.aimprosoft_1.0.0 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411) at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 193 more 2019-04-09 07:58:39.975 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8][status_jsp:872] com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSourceFactory 2019-04-09 07:58:39.979 ERROR [liferay/monitoring-1][ParallelDestination:55] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/monitoring, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=[{displayName=Main, portletId=main_INSTANCE_FxqlwYbtcN8u, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=0, name=main, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=null, stopWatch=0:00:00.055, timeout=0, user=20139}}, {displayName=Product Menu, portletId=com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=1, name=com_liferay_product_navigation_product_menu_web_portlet_ProductMenuPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.001, timeout=0, user=20139}}, {displayName=Search Bar, portletId=com_liferay_portal_search_web_search_bar_portlet_SearchBarPortlet_INSTANCE_templateSearch, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=5, name=com_liferay_portal_search_web_search_bar_portlet_SearchBarPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.005, timeout=0, user=20139}}, {displayName=User Personal Bar, portletId=com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=1, name=com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.001, timeout=0, user=20139}},

Comment: Please add the maven dependency you ad to the pom.xml

Comment: i`ve added them

Comment: Please only add the important part of the exception and format it so that it would be readable.

Comment: Are you implementing a custom ConnectionFactory inside your project? Liferay or the container already have a connection factory. You could check `InfrastructureUtil` for example.